# How do you show grid lines for both x axis and y axis in highchart?

Tags: jquery, highcharts, jquery-plugins

I want to draw a chart using highchart. By default, only the y axis grid lines are shown. How do you enable the option to show grid line for x axis as well?

Answer (score 12):

Set [`gridLineWidth`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineWidth) to 1 to enable grid lines. Like this:

```
xAxis: {
  gridLineWidth: 1
}, 
yAxis: {
  gridLineWidth: 1
}
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/7sj67gs6/

**API ref:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineWidth